# If both the Shadow and the Vorlons knew each other motivations, why did Morden ask the Shadow's question to Kosh?

Tags: babylon-5

Why did Morden ask the Shadow's question to Kosh? They knew perfectly each other.
Was it an error from Morden or was it a way to say 'hi. We are going to try it again after the last war'?

Comment: The only time Kosh was asked "What do you want?" was by Sheridan, who was just exasperated and wasn't aware of the significance. Morden and Kosh never met cordially; Kosh considered him as a pestilence.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He did not.  If you are thinking that was what happened when Kosh and Morden met in Signs and Portents, you misremember/misinterpreted the scene.  Morden was trying to avoid Kosh, and successfully did so earlier in the episode.  Kosh was confronting Morden, trying to get him off the station and preventing him from meeting the command staff (notice he never asked Sinclair), the implication is there was even a fight after the scene cut off, with dialogue later in the episode mentioning damage to Kosh's encouter suit.

Comment: +1 [Kosh was pretty unambiguous](https://youtu.be/g3QP2UsgybA)

Comment: Yeah. You are right. I misremembered it. I mixed that scene which the one where Morden went to Kosh's room. It was more than fifteen years ago when I watched it. ^^U It only came to my mind when I read about a possible reboot.